# How can I draw a line graph on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, graph

I am new to iPad programming.

I want to draw line graph in iPad. I am using Xcode 4.2. can someone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel. There is an open source project called [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). If you want to learn while implementing, look at and understand the source code.

Comment: what is this core plot i am not getting any thing in this ,where are sample programs ?

Comment: do some google and then ask questions.Here is link for you:-http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_4_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper: thanx dude.. that link really helped, but what if i need to create dynamic graph ? do i need to use any software for that ?

Comment: that you need to think i have created line graph using the code that is given on this site but i am not going to write full code for you

Comment: any software you know in which i can draw dynamic graph ? except core plot,because core plot not working in Xcode 4.2